# Php PayPal IPN returns INVALID

Tags: php, https, paypal-ipn

I know that there have been a few changes to the PayPal IPN system as of May 15th, 2018. I happen to be in the middle of implementing my first IPN listener; and **I'm not sure if I'm lost because of my resources (including SO posts, some dating back to 2009 on this subject) have been obsolesced by PayPal's changes, or merely because I am inexperienced in this field.**

My suspicion is that I am pointing to the incorrect PayPal address:

```
$fh = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com',443,$errno,$errstr,30);
//$fh = fsockopen('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com',80,$errno,$errstr,30);
//$fh = fsockopen('https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',80,$errno,$errstr,30);
```

The first address completes in a successful handshake with PayPal, but returns INVALID as the IPN response. The second two handshake, but don't pass the `if (!$fh)` test.

I have tried both the code below, and the CURL code found in Chris Muench's answer here: [PayPal IPN returns invalid in sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323331/paypal-ipn-returns-invalid-in-sandbox)

```
<?php
// Paypal IPN code

header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); // send header

$resp = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $parm => $var){
    $var = urlencode(stripslashes($var));
    $resp .= "&$parm=$var";
}

$httphead = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$httphead .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$httphead .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($resp) . "\r\n\r\n";

// create a ="file handle" for writing to a URL to paypal.com on Port 443 (the IPN port)
$errno ='';
$errstr='';

$fh = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com',443,$errno,$errstr,30);
//$fh = fsockopen('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com',443,$errno,$errstr,30);
//$fh = fsockopen('https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',443,$errno,$errstr,30);

if (!$fh) {
    // if-fh does not work - cnxn FAILED
} 
else{
    // Connection opened, so spit back the response and get PayPal's view whether it was an authentic notification
    fputs ($fh,$httphead.$resp);
    while (!feof($fh)){
        $readresp = fgets ($fh, 1024);
        if (strcmp(trim($readresp),"VERIFIED") == 0){
            // if-fh works - cnxn OPEN';
            // WE ALL WIN!!
        }
        else if(strcmp(trim($readresp),"INVALID") == 0){
            // A possible hacking attempt, or
            // In my case, a possible hacking false-positive
        }
    }
fclose ($fh);
}
?>
```

I'm testing using the IPN simulator in my sandbox account.

None of the SO recommended solutions have worked.

Please help!

Comment: PayPal is reporting a problem with their Sandbox environment and the new "ipnpb" address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, this url seems to be working fine: `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`